# Shred an internal or system partition

Tags: root-access, internal-storage, security, file-system, storage

There are quite a few apps that lets a user delete the media or data partitions so it won't be recoverable - by re-writing "junk" data over and over again on the free storage space.

Still, is there any way (app, ROM, tool, etc.) that does the same process for the system partitions? (assuming that root or custom ROM/recovery image is required for such process)

Comment: The entire partition, or just free space?

Comment: Just the free space would be enough.
Perhaps I can use the root access to run commands like these? http://superuser.com/a/223312/176339

Comment: You can use @ followed by the name to whom you're trying to notify. Here, your notification probably didn't reach *Matthew Read*. http://android.stackexchange.com/editing-help#comment-formatting

Comment: @MatthewRead FYI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eventually I solved it by connecting the device to my pc, running `adb shell` and then running `su` in order to grant root privileges.

After that, to list all the partitions, I used the `df` command - and in each partition I generated a file big enough to fill all of the free space with random data (generated using the command `dd if=/dev/urandom of=junkfile.txt bs=1048576 count=AmountOfMBs`, as explained [here](http://www.skorks.com/2010/03/how-to-quickly-generate-a-large-file-on-the-command-line-with-linux/)).

Note that this method still doesn't shred the space that's currently in use on the device, so before going through this whole process I did a factory reset and then signed-in with a dummy account.